# Large memory footprint on simple Java code

Tags: java, performance, memory, optimization, memory-management

I'm solving a problem at `spoj` and the system shows that my program took `1341M` of memory. When I look at submissions in other languages, they required `~3M`, which is ~400 times less!

My code is below:

```
class Main {
    static List<BigInteger> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    static {
        BigInteger max = BigInteger.TEN.pow(100);

        numbers.add(BigInteger.ONE);
        numbers.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2l));
        BigInteger last = numbers.get(1);

        while (last.compareTo(max) <= 0) {
            numbers.add(numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1).add(numbers.get(numbers.size() - 2)));
            last = numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        BufferedReader bi = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line;
        String delims = " ";
        while ((line = bi.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, delims);
            BigInteger from = new BigInteger(tokenizer.nextToken());
            BigInteger to = new BigInteger(tokenizer.nextToken());

            if (from.equals(BigInteger.ZERO) && to.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                return;
            } else {
                System.out.println(countInRange(from, to));
            }
        }
    }

    public static int countInRange(BigInteger from, BigInteger to) {
        int fromIndex = Collections.binarySearch(numbers, from);
        fromIndex = fromIndex < 0 ? Math.abs(fromIndex) - 1 : fromIndex;
        int toIndex = Collections.binarySearch(numbers, to);
        toIndex = toIndex < 0 ? Math.abs(toIndex) - 1 : toIndex + 1;
        return toIndex - fromIndex;
    }
}
```

I suppose that `BufferedReader` is the cause of high memory consumption. Is it possible to significantly improve memory footprint in this case? I'm not talking about achieving `3M`, but at least being under `100M` or so.

Comment: To reproduce the problem, knowing the input to the program is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**First off**: How may elements are you keeping in `numbers`? Might be quite some as your max is 10 pow 100.

**Second**: Consider the Java Memory Model. 1341M is about as much as fits into 32bit Java VM. So maybe it's just that your while generating objects on the heap (all these shiny `new BigInteger`s), Java produced a lot of garbage memory. But if you don't set the options for your process right, it will not give it back to the OS.

Have you actually *tried* to run program with only 100M memory (by setting `-Xmx100m` option in your java call?

Consider creating a heap dump and check that (I recommend [Eclipse Memory Profiler](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to see what is eating your memory. My best guess at this point: It's either the vast amount of precomputed numbers (what are they? Seems like a Lucas sequence to me?) or just garbage waiting to be collected.

Answer (score 1):

**Quick check:** Are you sure the 1341MB of memory are not actually consumed by your IDE (e.g. Eclipse or Netbeans)?

I packaged your code into an executable Jar, on a Windows 7, x64 machine with 64b Oracle JRE 1.8.0.66. When running the code the system only shows ~10MB memory consumption. I generated a heap dump using:

```
java -agentlib:hprof=file=snapshot.hprof,format=b -jar number_counter.jar
```

When analyzing this with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, the memory footprint of the used objects was very low.

A few notes:

- *number* array should not be very large. As far as I understood it contains just a Fibonacci sequence that grows quite fast, therefore i only saw ~500 stored BigNumbers.
- There is no real reason for why BufferedReader should have a large footprint.  This is a heavily used object and I'm sure good optimization efforts have been invested in it.

**To conclude**, please check that your are monitoring the correct java process, make sure you use an up-to-date JRE and make sure you don't use some unnecessary memory management rules. Your code seems fine and the footprint should be less than 20 MB.